# Fill the remaining width when there is less column than expected with CSS grid display

Tags: html, css

I have my grid layout with `grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` meaning one row should have maximum 3 columns. So far so good, the next I want to achieve though is that when there is only a single (or two) column inside a row, I want it to fill the rest of the row, leaving no space behind.

```css
.grids {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grids">
  <div class="red">s</div>
  <div class="blue">s</div>
  <div class="yellow">s</div>
  <div class="yellow">a</div>
</div>
```

In this case, I want the last div (the one 'a' written inside) to be grown.

Comment: not doable with a grid. Thats works fine with flexboxes though.

Comment: @tacoshy I have found lots of good stuff doable with grid display, especially that auto-fill stuff and else. I have to do this with grid anyway.

Comment: doesnt matter if you have to do it with a grid or how much good stuff you found, it is still not doable with a css-grid. the css-grid does not allow for a last row adjustment. autfoill only works for the entire grid not only the last row as this function does not exist.